# How to change font to Helvetica Neue? None of answers here work!

Tags: xetex, pdf, tex-core, mactex

I am trying to change the entire document font to create a pdf out of this. But regardless of what I try, the font does not change. I have Helvetica installed on my machine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \textheight=10in
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \raggedright
\setmainfont{helvet}
    %\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{cg}
%\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lgrcmr}

\def\bull{\vrule height 0.8ex width .7ex depth -.1ex }

% DEFINITIONS FOR RESUME %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\area} [2] {
    \vspace*{-9pt}
    \begin{verse}
        \textbf{#1}   #2
    \end{verse}
}

\newcommand{\lineunder} {
    \vspace*{-8pt} \\
    \hspace*{-18pt} \hrulefill \\
}

\newcommand{\header} [1] {
    {\hspace*{-18pt}\vspace*{6pt} \textsc{#1}}
    \vspace*{-6pt} \lineunder
}

\newcommand{\employer} [3] {
    { \textbf{#1} (#2)\\ \underline{\textbf{\emph{#3}}}\\  }
}

\newcommand{\contact} [3] {
    \vspace*{-10pt}
    \begin{center}
        {\Huge \scshape {#1}}\\
        #2 \\ #3
    \end{center}
    \vspace*{-8pt}
}

\newenvironment{achievements}{
    \begin{list}
        {$\bullet$}{\topsep 0pt \itemsep -2pt}}{\vspace*{4pt}
    \end{list}
}

\newcommand{\schoolwithcourses} [4] {
    \textbf{#1} #2 $\bullet$ #3\\
    #4 \\
    \vspace*{5pt}
}

\newcommand{\school} [4] {
    \textbf{#1} #2 $\bullet$ #3\\
    #4 \\
}
% END RESUME DEFINITIONS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{document}
\vspace*{-40pt}
```

Comment: you are mixing pdflatex and xelatex code. Which engine are you actually using?

Comment: I'm using LaTex. At least this what it says on the top right next to "Typeset."

Comment: And why did you tag your question with xetex in this case?

Comment: My bad! I don't even know the difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the Helvetica Neue font (OpenType or TrueType) you need to load the `fontspec` package and typeset with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Change the argument of `\setmainfont` according to the specific font you have installed (which I do not know).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{HelveticaNeue}
% Use the the correct name of the font family!

\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the version of the fonts from Linotype, with the same filenames as on their webpage, the following might work for you. (Not tested.)

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[HelveticaNeueLTPro]{
   Ligatures = Common,
   UprightFont = *-LT,
   ItalicFont = *-LtIt,
   BoldFont = *-Md,
   BoldItalicFont = *-MdIt,
   Extension = .otf }

\setmainfont{HelveticaNeueLTPro}
\setsansfont{HelveticaNeueLTPro}
```

Tweak these settings if you have different filenames or want a heavier or lighter weight.  Compile in LuaLaTeX, or perhaps XeLaTeX.  If you need math as well, you could load `unicode-math` and set a sans-serif font such as Fira Math as your math font.